# Error in tabula tabula-py when specifying area parameter

Tags: python, tabula

I am getting an error when I specify the area in the following code:

```
data = tb.read_pdf(pdf_file, guess=False, stream=True, pandas_options ={'header': None}, encoding="utf-8", multiple_tables =False, area = [136,10,10,10], pages ='1', columns = [124,150,355,425,484,543])
```

This is the error i get:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't add an oblique ruling.`

Works fine if I do not specify the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not providing the correct coordinates for area. The list should contain coordinates as [top,left,bottom,right].

> area (list of float, list of list of float, optional):
> Portion of the page to analyze(top,left,bottom,right).
> Default is entire page.

For instance:

```
data = tb.read_pdf(pdf_path, area=[126,149,212,462], pages=2)
```

Comment: you were right. thanks.